# How to type a generator function with typscript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to send a value back to the generator function using `next` which seems to complicate typing this function

```
function* gen(): IterableIterator<string> {
    const a = yield 'test';       // Line A
    console.log('received:' + a);
    yield a + '';
}

const x = gen();

console.log('main:' + x.next(99));  // Line B
console.log('main' + x.next());
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-s5uspr?file=index.ts)

In my VSCODE I get the following error for Line A

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

And In Stackblitz/demo I get an error for Line B

```
Argument of type '[99]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[] | [undefined]'.
  Type '[99]' is not assignable to type '[undefined]'.
    Type '99' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2345)
```

So my question is, how can I type the value I provide with `next`?

Comment: [TypeScript 3.6 introduced the `Generator<Y,R,N>` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html#stricter-generators) so you can give `gen()` the return type of `Generator<string, void, number>` instead of `IterableIterator<string>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJjRW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing

Comment: Thats it, stricter generators, thnx!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript 3.6 introduced support for [stricter generator typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html#stricter-generators), including the `Generator<Y, R, N>` type where the `Y` type parameter corresponds to the type `yield`ed from the generator function body (the same as the `T` in `Iterator<T>`), the `R` type parameter corresponds to the type `return`ed from the generator function body, and the `N` type parameter corresponds to the type passed into the `next()` method of the iterator.  Since you are passing `string` to `yield` and passing `number` to `next` and not `return`ing anything, it looks like you want your generator return type to be something like `Generator<string, void, number>`:

```
function* gen(): Generator<string, void, number> {
    const a: number = yield 'test';
    console.log('received: ' + a);
    yield a + '';
}

const x = gen();
const y = x.next(99);
if (y.done) throw new Error();
console.log("main: " + y.value) // main: test
const z = x.next(); // received: undefined
if (z.done) throw new Error();
console.log("main: " + z.value) // main: undefined
```

It *is* a little weird that `a` is typed as `number` but could be `undefined`, even with [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks) enabled.  But that's what happens if you call `x.next()` without an input.  This is apparently working as intended [as per this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30790#issuecomment-481201957) on [ms/TS#30790](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30790), the implementing pull request.  So if you ever plan to do something that would explode if `undefined` comes out of that `yield`, like this:

```
function* gen(): Generator<string, void, number> {
    const a: number = yield 'test';
    console.log('received:' + a.toFixed(2)); // ERROR if a is undefined
    yield a.toFixed(2);
}
```

then you should probably manually augment the `N` type parameter with `undefined` to be safe:

```
function* gen(): Generator<string, void, number | undefined> {
// -------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^
    const a = yield 'test';
    console.log('received: ' + (a?.toFixed(2)));
    yield a?.toFixed(2) || "undefined";
}

const x = gen();
const y = x.next(99);
if (y.done) throw new Error();
console.log("main: " + y.value) // main: test
const z = x.next(); // received: undefined
if (z.done) throw new Error();
console.log("main: " + z.value) // main: undefined
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAZaUDKIBmyDeAsAFDFJlLYCuw8ALgJYD2wAVEgOYTAAUAlAFxIA4lwgAnELUZiAPFFpj6wdgBokAN0b0AJmuCUwAI3EA+JISLkrSeM3lIQg-UfFIAvEgCe9CABttSADktNC0gQDcpNZktsBQjL4QAHS+jOzcgWIQiPTqENqCgUgA1A68kZbRSAD01bHxiSlp3CBJUgBi9AAe+dwATLzlNdVIAKIASuMA8uMAhFHR3n4BICVBEQtIAL7Em-W0SF3uHFx8FXt2B57HXUnAEF203ACcz+Wb9NhI3J5J2swQXhIWgACzEjAA7kh7lDRmJwWIzhc4glkql0gAiMAgJSCDFrX7qEC+SiA4ZIbG44GhZH2ABeNzuDye70qZE+3zpfwBQNB4KhMLG8OkSLZNjsqKamMpwDxay5RJJZNqFJxsqQ1G0EGwSnyxB2JCIoEgsAQyAAstIIFhcOZdmKqDQGMw2JweAJhKIJFJZPJFMo1JodHoDMYxEgAD4a4BanX3bRmCxVcVxA6rDxLfxBELyDZiqz1SXojJZHJ5ApBNYtAD8bUYnR62n6g1ZyczK1rHW6vQGkajGM12t12gxFSsBtpByOHjdooLly8jPujxebzH5A5P25915YMh0IgsOFiNb5ELjWLWLVctKhOJpKBKplghztEnSAZHluy5Z4XJpYgXJ8kEQc4z1MVNy5f4d2BPcBUPIUETnM8JQvZorypfFSgVe9lRGZ9o1jYd9SAA)